# 1997 Putnam Competition. B1: Evaluate, $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{6n-1}\min\Big(\Big\{\frac i {6n}\Big\},\Big\{\frac i {3n}\Big\}\Big).$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

For each positive integer $n$, evaluate
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{6n-1}\min\Big(\Big\{\frac i {6n}\Big\},\Big\{\frac i {3n}\Big\}\Big).$$
$\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

The solution of the exercice is given as follows:
It is trivial to check that $\frac{m}{6n}=\{\frac{m}{6n}\}\leq
\{\frac{m}{3n}\}$ for $1\leq m\leq 2n$, that
$1-\frac{m}{3n}=\{\frac{m}{3n}\}\leq \{\frac{m}{6n}\}$ for $2n\leq
m\leq 3n$, that $\frac{m}{3n}-1=\{\frac{m}{3n}\}\leq \{\frac{m}{6n}\}$
for $3n\leq m\leq 4n$, and that $1-\frac{m}{6n}=\{\frac{m}{6n}\}\leq
\{\frac{m}{3n}\}$ for $4n\leq m\leq 6n$.  Therefore the desired sum is
$$\sum_{m=1}^{2n-1} \frac{m}{6n}
 +\sum_{m=2n}^{3n-1} \left(1-\frac{m}{3n} \right) 
 +\sum_{m=3n}^{4n-1} \left(\frac{m}{3n}-1 \right) + \sum_{m=4n}^{6n-1} \left(
1-\frac{m}{6n} \right)=n.$$

I checked by giving small values to $n=1, 2,$ but the above answer does not give the right value. For $n=1,2,$ I found $S_1=2.33,$ and $S_2=4.33.$ It seems that the correct sum of the series is $2n+\frac {1}{3}$. Any help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put the correct statement of the exercise in the body of your post.

Comment: Thanks,  I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem uses the slightly nonstandard and now unfortunate notation $$\{x\} = \min(x - \lfloor x\rfloor, \lceil x \rceil - x).$$

The [original problem statement](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1997.pdf) explicitly says this.

> Let $\{x\}$ denote the distance  between  the  real  number $x$ and the nearest integer.

This is **not** the fractional part of $x$, which is also commonly denoted $\{x\}$ and defined (at least for positive reals, though [there are several different conventions for negative reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part)) by $$\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor.$$

I think your calculations are still incorrect even if you use the fractional part rather than the integer-distance definition, but that might be a different error.  I get $$S'_n = \frac{3}{4}\left(3x-1\right)$$ using the incorrect convention, which does not match your values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thurmond, now I understand where I was wrong.

Comment: @Kamal Perhaps you should accept the answer, then.